# span text and image to the right but both of them aligns to the left

Tags: html, css, css-float

Here's what I am trying to do:

[image]

Just a simple alignment but if I float the image to the right it goes to the other side if I place the text first

https://jsfiddle.net/3gc0qjzo/

```
<span>
      <img src="img"/>
      <p>Learn More<p>
</span>

span img {
  float: right;
}
span p {
  display: block;
}
```

If I put the image first then the text and do a `float:left;` it works find but im not sure how to align them both if the image goes last.

Comment: My suggestion is forget about floats and make the parent: span into a `display: flex;` then you don't have to put the image first.  Heres good info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex

```
   span{
     display:flex;
     flex-direction:row;
     align-items:center; 
   }
```